# Slope of a line as a row vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, slope

I'm not able to understand the concepts behind the following problem that appeared on my homework.

> Consider the line defined by ${w}^\mathsf{T}x + b = 0$ and  two points
>   $x_1$ and $x_2$ that lie on the line:
>
> - Calculate ${w}^\mathsf{T}\left(x_1 - x_2\right)$

I used substitution(substituting x1,x2 in line equation) to derive that the answer is $0$.

> - This tells us that ${w}$ is [orthogonal/collinear] to the line.

From trial and error, I figured out the answer is **orthogonal** (it was a multiple choice question).

What topics should I revisit/study to visualize and solve such questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $w \neq 0$ such that $w^Tx+b = 0$, and since $x_1$ and $x_2$ lies on the line, then they must satisfy the equation.

$$w^Tx_1 + b = 0$$
$$w^Tx_2+b=0$$

Subtracting the equations, we have

$$w^T(x_1-x_2)=0$$

We can write the above as an inner product.

$$\langle w, x_1-x_2 \rangle=0$$

$$\|w\| \|x_1-x_2\| \cos \theta =0$$

If $w$ and $x_1-x_2$ are non-zero, then $\cos \theta = 0$, that is $\theta$ must be an odd multiple of $90^\circ$.

Hence $w$ and $x_1-x_2$ is perpendicular.

$x_1-x_2$ is the direction of the line, hence $w$ must be perpendicular to the line.

Potential relevant topic: inner product, multivariate calculus, linear algebra, vector.